# Find last created record RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

How could I write a test to find the last created record?

This is the code I want to test:

`Post.order(created_at: :desc).first`

I'm also using factorybot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've called your method 'last_post':

```
def self.last_post
  Post.order(created_at: :desc).first
end
```

Then in your test:

```
it 'should return the last post' do
  expect(Post.last_post).to eq(Post.last)
end
```

On another note, the easiest way to write your code is simply

```
Post.last
```

And you shouldn't really be testing the outcome of ruby methods (you should be making sure the correct ruby methods are called), so if you did:

```
def self.last_post
  Post.last
end
```

Then your test might be:

```
it 'should send the last method to the post class' do
   expect(Post).to receive(:last)
   Post.last_post
end
```

You're not testing the outcome of the 'last' method call - just that it gets called.

Comment: Using `.last` without any specified column will default to ordering on the ID column for the model, which means this will only work if sequential IDs are being used (and ideally they shouldn't be). https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/last

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is incorrect. Simply doing `Post.last` will order the posts by the `ID`, not by when they were created.

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/last

If you're using sequential IDs (and ideally you shouldn't be) then obviously this will work, but if not then you'll need to specify the column to sort by. So either:

```
def self.last_post
  order(created_at: :desc).first
end
```

or:

```
def self.last_post
  order(:created_at).last
end
```

Personally I'd look to do this as a scope rather than a dedicated method.

```
scope :last_created -> { order(:created_at).last }
```

This allows you to create some nice chains with other scopes, such as if you had one to find all posts by a particular user/account, you could then chain this pretty cleanly:

```
Post.for_user(user).last_created
```

Sure you can chain methods as well, but if you're dealing with Query interface methods I feel scopes just make more sense, and tend to be cleaner.

If you wanted to test that it returns the correct record, in your test you could do something like:

```
let!(:last_created_post) { factory_to_create_post }

. . . 

it "returns the correct post"
  expect(Post.last_post).to eq(last_created_post)
end
```

If you wanted to have an even better test, you could create a couple records before the last record to verify the method under test is pulling the correct result and not just *a* result from a singular record.